# Why does video conversion lower quality so much?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
for %i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -y -i "%i" -vf scale=1280:720 -crf 17 -c:v libx265 "1%~ni.mp4"
```

before and after conversion

[image: before and after conversion]

Not only is file size bigger with crf 17, but it's also much worse quality. Any better way to do this?

Comment: You do not specify the dimensions of your input file. Are you blowing up videos? https://gist.github.com/steven2358/ba153c642fe2bb1e47485962df07c730

Comment: @r2d3 It's 1080 converted to 720. 120 FPS 24 mbit

Answer (score 1):

Read here about the -crf values:
https://gist.github.com/steven2358/ba153c642fe2bb1e47485962df07c730
Start with single operations to determine the effect on quality and size.

Every reencoding lowers the quality.

The author in the link above states:
The default value is 23, and visually lossless compression corresponds to -crf 18.

You are using 17 instead for even higher quality which comes at the price of additional storage.

I only see a quality loss on top of the shoe. Everthing else is fine.
"So much" is not a quantitative measure.

There is a measure for quality realized in a compressed video stream called PSNR.

German link:
https://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_common_library/dl_news_from_rs/199/N199_Video-Bildqualitaet-messen_d.pdf